# Android Studio Subversion option

Tags: android, svn, android-studio

Suddenly subversion option has been gone from my android Studio as marked in image[image]

I have re-installed android studio still I cannot see subversion option.

any idea regarding this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to `Settings -> Plugins` and mark `Subversion integration`. Click `apply`, then restart Android Studio.